# Where does my weight come from?

Tags: weight-loss, body-fat, muscle-mass

I weigh quite a lot and I am trying to lose weight.

I am currently 6 feet tall and my weight is 216 pounds, which is clearly too much.

I have been working out doing mainly clap pushups, pullups, and throwing a medicine ball and playing basketball

I have never lifted weights in my life.

The thing is, I am not really that fat, and I recently got my body fat measured from a doctor, with it coming out around 18%, which is ridiculous. It would give me an FFMI (Fat Free Mass Index) of 23.48, without ever lifting weights or anything like that.

Something has to be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Your 'natural' body-mass percentages are hugely affected by genetics. Your hormone levels control how much muscle-mass you will have with any given level of activity.

It's entirely possible you're genetically gifted. If you start lifting weights more regularly, and get a solid plan for your diet, you could end-up being quite muscular.

The flip side is the body-fat % test might be waaayyyy off. Was it a body-caliper test? They can have major discrepancies, even when done by a doctor.

Comment: Yes it was a calipher test, it could be off, but when I compare myself to pictures of people who have a similar body fat percentage, I don't think I am over 20%. I am muscular but by no means huge. I don't really want to gain a lot of muscle mass, I play basketball and feel too heavy, I am quite explosive especially in short distance sprints but run out of gas quickly and do not jump as high as I should be jumping. I just carry too much weight.

Comment: If your goal is just general health and basketball, then you should be able to cut calories and drop fat without losing much muscle-mass. Keep up with the pushups/pullups/squats.

Comment: no, m, goal is to jump higher and run faster and I am concerned about my strength to weight ratio. My legs would need to generate much more force than another person with the weight I am carrying. Do large bones play a role in overall weight? I do have very big joints but I heard the while skeleton only amounts to 10% of the whole bodyweight or something like that.